# Como mudar a cor do ícone de notificação?

Tags: android, push-notification, icons, notifyicon

Tenho um aplicativo com notificação por push.
Porém o ícone que eu atribuo para a notificação fica com a cor cinza por inteiro.

Quero saber como faço para ter ícones coloridos na notificação por push, como estes exemplos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A implementação dos ícones coloridos tem haver com o minSDK?

Existe alguma documentação ou código exemplo para que eu apresente o ícone colorido?